# import opencv vs import cv2

Tags: python, macos, opencv, pip

I recently installed opencv-python-3.4.0.12 via pip install on Mac OS. When I run the Python interpreter, `import cv2` works fine whereas `import opencv` raises ModuleNotFoundError. However, when I run the Python3 Interpreter, `import opencv` works fine whereas `import cv2` raises ModuleNotFoundError.

What is the reason behind this difference and on a related note, should I use `import opencv` or `import cv2`? Does `cv2` refer to OpenCV version 2?

Comment: `cv2` module is the right one to use. Whatever provides `opencv` must be some nonsense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should import `cv2`. OpenCV releases two types of Python interfaces, `cv` and `cv2`. latest one is `cv2`. [This](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-macos/) will give you an idea whether you have installed `opencv` correctly.

Comment: this answer is partially wrong. the `opencv-python` and sibling packages provide a `cv2` import. the recommended import is `import cv2 as cv`. no package currently provides a `cv` "interface".

Answer (score 6):

The naming of `cv2` is a historical accident.

History lesson: OpenCV began as a C API. The first Python bindings back then used the `cv` import. With OpenCV version 2.0, a C++ API was introduced. That is also when C++ includes saying `#include <opencv2/...>` showed up. The C++ API uses the `cv::` namespace. The Python import was now called `cv2`, and carried the old C API in the `cv2.cv` namespace.

The `2` basically just means "The new API".

Since then, versions 3.x and 4.x, "the C++ API" is still the primary API, and currently the *only* API, because the C API was removed. However, the location of headers has *not* changed with new major versions and the name of the Python module import also has *not* changed.

The `opencv-python` packages *only* provide the `cv2` import. That is the import for all v3.x and 4.x versions, i.e. **the current version**, and probably will carry into v5.x. The **recommended import and usage** is:

```py
import cv2 as cv # to mirror the `cv::` namespace
# use cv.imread() and so on
```

**There is no `opencv` import.** If that "worked", it's wrong and something is *tricking* you. Check the installed packages and remove anything shady. The only trustworthy packages giving you OpenCV in Python are the official ones, which is [**`opencv-python` on PyPI**](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) and its sibling packages (package with additional contrib modules, package excluding GUI modules).

There is no `cv` import. In the future, these packages may be changed to drop the old name and offer the `cv` import directly.